TV series where heroes are teleported into game
I saw this live-action show on the television several years ago, so can't remember which country this series were produced by. I think there was teenage girl and probably other heroes who got in the game made by some of their relatives using the computer device like joystick or something. Virtual reality didn't look like CG image, it was absolutely cinematic. Gameplay was like quest involving the use of different items which the heroes had to seek. Location was like some island inhabited by the people who don't know about the latest technologies. One of the most important things is that NPC's in the game were sure that they are alive and their world is real. Also, part of the plot was in that the game wasn't completed, and in one episode there was an empty white location without anything.
The plot described above was spanned to all series, not just one or several episodes.

Was it animated or live-action?

@Walt live-action

Sounds a bit like one episode of Warehouse 13 (crossover episode including Eureka's Fargo). Do you remember whether this has been one episode's specific content or whether the whole setting spanned multiple episodes?

@Mario It was the whole setting spanned to series, not just single episode. I've seen this Warehouse 13 episode, and no, this is different show. BTW, this episode should receive award for the poorest virtual reality ever IMO.

A friend pointed me to the answer, it's the Pirate Islands series produced by Australian channel Network Ten in 2003: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0307803/

A freak accident sends three Australian kids into a computer-generated
  world of pirates and swashbuckling heroes. The kids must help a group
  of adventurers find a buried treasure and a way back to the real
  world.

